# while GetKeyState sends ESC for no reason

Tags: autohotkey

I have made a function tho after releasing the button (f4) the function sends ESC 2 times
I countered it by writing Send {esc} after closing the function with }
tho I can still see it happen and it triggers me.
Is there a fix?

```
~^f4::
DllCall("mouse_event", "UInt", 0x01, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 950)
Sleep, 100
Send {x}
Sleep, 100
while GetKeyState("f4")
{
Sleep, 100
Send {r}
Sleep, 100
Send {enter}
Sleep, 30
Send {esc}
Sleep, 100
DllCall("mouse_event", "UInt", 0x01, "UInt", 0, "UInt", -950)
Sleep, 100
Send {e}
Sleep, 100
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 50
Send {enter}
Sleep, 10
Send {esc}
Sleep, 100
DllCall("mouse_event", "UInt", 0x01, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 950)
}
Send {esc}
return
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want your program to do- could you please clarify this?

Comment: @Spyre Hi I don't really want to explain everything since it's more of a private project, everything you see works perfectly, but after releasing the button the scripts presses ESC twice, that is the problem I want to get fixe. Could you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution based on what I understand:

```
~^f4::
DllCall("mouse_event", "UInt", 0x01, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 950)
Sleep, 100
Send {x}
Sleep, 100
while GetKeyState("f4")
{
Sleep, 100
Send {r}
Sleep, 100
Send {enter}
Sleep, 30
if !GetKeyState("f4")
    break
Send {esc}
Sleep, 100
DllCall("mouse_event", "UInt", 0x01, "UInt", 0, "UInt", -950)
Sleep, 100
Send {e}
Sleep, 100
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5
Send {Left}
Sleep, 50
Send {enter}
Sleep, 10
if !GetKeyState("f4")
    break
Send {esc}
Sleep, 100
DllCall("mouse_event", "UInt", 0x01, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 950)
}
Send {esc}
return
```